# Есть ли сервис для изменения разрешения картинки под все экраны Android?

Tags: android, изображения

Как и все начинающие разработчики, столкнулся с обычной проблемой, а именно: сделать так, чтобы моё приложение выглядело на всех экранах одинаково. Сам оптимизировал свою программу под **Full HD**, т.к. имею **Samsung galaxy S4**, но, это было очевидно, я увидел, что на телефоне друга картинки выглядели куда больше, т.к. разрешение у его телефона было поменьше и интерфейс был ужасен.
Хотелось бы узнать, есть ли сервис, или сайт, или какой-нибудь способ залить изо, и из него будут сделаны изо под каждый экран, которые мне уже останется залить в папки для разных экранов при создании проекта. Если такового нету, то скажите, как вы с этим справлялись, или, может, есть способ какой удобный. Предложение по созданию нескольких эмулятор на **Eclipse** с разными экранами не предлагать, и так знаю. (Для меня этот метод просто ужасен, т.к. процесс затягивается на О-О-ОЧЕНЬ долгий срок.)
Заранее благодарен всем отозвавшимся.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Android Asset Studio](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html)
Все легко и интуитивно.

Comment: Это оно!!! Вы мой спаситель!
___

На мой вопрос вы дали ответ даже больше, чем нужно.

Comment: @BORSHEVIK, и еще в Android Studio можно сразу смотреть превью лэйаута на нескольких устройствах.
http://static.electronicsweekly.com/eyes-on-android/wp-content/uploads/sites/8/2013/05/android-studio.png

Comment: К сожалению, пользуюсь Eclipse, но уже давно подумывал перейти на AS - больше приемуществ. Может, если знаете, посоветуете какой сервис или что-то подобное по переносу проекта из Eclipse в AS, а то самому переносить, то можно и сломать что-нибудь.

Comment: @BORSHEVIK https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html Перейти можно достаточно легко. Все основные библиотеки можно автоматически подтягивать из maven репозитория(т.е. не нужно хранить jar сборки). Ну и вообще гугл AS поддерживает и развивает. Есть много удобств: например группировка ресурсов. https://www.dropbox.com/s/l6ivj3yiqy6q6zy/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202014-09-16%2016.01.10.png?dl=0

Comment: Спасибо, тут вы мне тоже очень помогли.

Answer (score 1):

Я для решения таких проблем пользуюсь [genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/), что советую и вам ) Сервис позволяет тоже создавать эмуляторы, но они работают в 10 раз быстрее, чем нативные.

Comment: Впринципе работу ускорит,но не совсем то, что хотелось, но всё равно спасибо. Надеюсь всё таки на то, что кто-нибудь знает способ получше